# User Defined Function with Strings giving error

Tags: python

| Date | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 24-Jun-68 | Bill |

I would like to create a function that transforms this Date into a working date format. However, I am unable to get this function to return anything I am getting an error that says. AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'. The function is below

````
    day=x.str.split("-")[0]
    month=x.str.split("-")[1]
    year=x.str.split("-")[2]
    return month+"/"+day+"/"+"19"+year

df['New Date'] = df['Date'].apply(get_date)```
````

Answer (score 0):

`str` is supposed to be the string you are passing. So it should be `x.split("-")[0]`, `x.split("-")[1]`, and `x.split("-")[2]`

Comment: Still getting issues AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split', Even though the value being passed is a string

Comment: This means the value of x is a float. You need to cast it into a string using `str(x).split("-")[0]`

Comment: But wait, if it is a float does it have the "-" character? Can you give a sample value of x?

Answer (score 0):

.split() is a string method, you can use it directly on the string you are splitting.

```
day, month, year = x.split('-')
return f'{month}/{day}/19{year}'
```

Comment: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)

Comment: This only works for the date format provided in the question, that is, containing two dashes: "day-month-year"